# I am beginner trying to update status on view table laravel but i am getting controller error that (Attempt to read property "status" on null)

Tags: php, laravel

**invoices/index.blade.php**

```
    <td>

                              <form action="{{url('/invoice_status_upadated')}}" method="POST">
                                
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                              <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                <option value="0" {{$inv->status == 0 ? 'selected':''}}>Pending </option>
                                <option value="1" {{$inv->status == 1 ? 'selected':''}}>In Process </option>
                                <option value="2" {{$inv->status == 2 ? 'selected':''}}>Completed </option>
                                <option value="3" {{$inv->status == 3 ? 'selected':''}}>Cancelled </option>
                                

                                  <?php 
                                  if ($inv->status == 0){
                                    echo "selected";
                                  }
                                    ?>
                                    
          
                                <?php 
                                if ($inv->status == 1){
          
                                  echo "selected";
                                }
                                
                                  ?>
                                 <?php 
                                 if ($inv->status == 2){
           
                                   echo "selected";
                                 }
                                 
                                   ?>                                         
                                <?php 
                                if ($inv->status == 3){
          
                                  echo "selected";
                                }
                                
                                  ?> 
                            
    
                            </select>
                            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-success">Update</button>

                            </div>
                              </form>

                            
                            </td>
```

**/TemplateContorller**

```
public function invoice_status_upadated(Request $request){ 
    $data= Invoice::find($request->status);
    $data->status=$request->$data->status;
    $data->save();
    return redirect('invoices');
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/invoice_status_upadated', 'App\Http\Controllers\TemplateController@invoice_status_upadated')->name('invoice_status_upadated');
```

**View**

[image: view for table]

**error**

[image]

Comment: The error says that `$data` is `null`. `Invoice::find($request->status);` the `find` method here requires an `id` for an invoice to find, `$request->status` doesn't sound like it holds an `id`. `dd($data)` after `$data= Invoice::find($request->status);` to see what it contains.

Comment: yes that might be the problem so can you help me what should i do in the function to update the status

Comment: Add a hidden field to your form that holds the `invoice_id` (from the first column) so you know which invoice you have edited/need to update

Comment: Pretty sure you can also remove all those `if( ...echo "selected";`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="status">
```

And also in your controller you have to change :-

```
$data = Invoice::find($invoice_id);
$data->status = $request->status;
$data->save();
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: yes correct that was the issue... Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `$data->status=$request->$data->status;` do `$data->status = $request->status;`

$request does not have the data from the model, which is in the $data variable.

Comment: still facing the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Hi first of all you need to async you select tag with name tag and set it to status
for example

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="status">
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $inv->id }}" name="inv_id"/>
```

then in your controller first of all you need to validate your request incomping data for mor information please see [this in laravel documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation)

after that you need to change your code like this

```
$data= Invoice::find($request->inv_id);
$data->status= $data->status;
```

Comment: `$request->status` is not the correct parameter for the `find` method - there most likely is no Invoice with an `id` of 0. `$data->status= isset($data->status) ? $data->status : 0;` What is that supposed to do? Set status to the value it already has or to zero?

Comment: @brombeer Thank you for reminding me, I have corrected the request code

Comment: thank a lot for your time the error is sorted by just adding hidden field invoice id so that sorted it out :) again thank you